# Replace first comma in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a way in C# to replace first occurrence of a regular expression in a string.

So if `string = ",1,2,3,4,5"` I want to do something like

```
string = replacefirst(",","")
```

to always give the result:

```
string = "1,2,3,4,5"
```

Comment: The post title says "semicolon", but your example uses commas.

Comment: If you have all your elements in an array you can use `String.Join()`, so that you don't get into this post handling.

Comment: May not be relevant for your case, but if your source string is created using String.Join(listOfNumbers,",") then you won't have extra comma (leading/trailing) in the result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Trim for that:

```
var myTrimmedString = myString.TrimStart(',');
```

Answer (score 8):

```
string s = "a;b;c;";
Regex rx = new Regex(";");
string s2 = rx.Replace(s, "", 1);  //"ab;c;"
```

Comment: I like the way this answers the question *title* perfectly. +1

Answer (score 5):

In a regex, "^" means "beginning"

```
Regex.Replace(",1,2,3,4,5", "^,", "")
```

gives `1,2,3,4,5`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if(yourString.Startswith(','))
      yourString = yourString.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the regex to match the first semicolon only.

Answer (score 0):

```
string MyString = ",1,2,3,4,6";
MessageBox.Show(MyString.Substring(1, MyString.Length-1));
```

Comment: This is equal to: MyString.Substring(1)